# Импорт сторонних модулей python на хостинге

Tags: python-3.x, django, хостинг

Всем привет.
Кто может подсказать или дать направление, куда копать?

Установил на хостинг, виртуальное окружение, запихнул туда Django. Создал проект и загрузил свое приложение. И вот все бы ничего, но использую модуль `requests`. Установил его так же в виртуальное окружение проверил, что библиотека там есть.
Но... Но выдает ошибку, что мол модуль с таким именем не найдет. Причем модули стандартной питоновской библиотеки нормально работают, например `time`, `json`.

Запустил пайтон в SSH клиенте, библиотека импортируется без проблем и работает. Что-то наверное в настройках проекта?

Мой первый опыт загрузки приложения на хостинг, поэтому не понимаю куда копать.

Comment: Обратитесь в поддержку хостинга.

Comment: Некоторые хостинги всячески ограничивают взаимодействие с системой. Для Django-проектов хорошим выбором будет PythonAnywhere, но я советую VPS. Со своим сервером (хоть и виртуальным) таких проблем не будет никогда.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать дальше.

Comment: Уточните, это именно хостинг или VPS?